# System.Diagnostics.Trace cannot be used in the C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Here is the problem!

I have an existing VS C# project and I would like to write some of the logs when I build the project in release mode. 
When trying to do so, I noticed that there are plenty of pages here which asks us to use Trace.WriteLine function which is within System.Diagnostics.

Every time I type Trace, the only option I get is Tracing!!
Compiler somehow fails to get the Trace option .
Debug.writeline works.

Under project properties Trace contants have been enabled for both release and debug modes .

Anybody's help here to point out the missing link would be of a great help.

Many Thanks,
Sharvari

Comment: Are you missing references?

Comment: What kind of C# project? That class is only available in desktop projects, not PCL nor many others.

Comment: Glubus: is there any spcific file or repository to be referenced? I have included System.Spatial, Microsoft.Data.Odata, Microsoft.Data.Edm, Microsoft 3013 runtime

Comment: Lex Li: This is a  project built for Windows 8.1, Windows phone 8.1.